# How to solve those equations

Tags: equation-solving

**Question 1:**

I want to find the expression of the function `f[x]` of the following equation:

```
Solve[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x^3 - 1}] == x, f[x], x]
```

But the code above returns an empty set. What can I do to solve this problem?

**Question 2:**

```
A = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, xx}}; B = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, y, 0}, {0, 
   0, -1}}; 
P = Array[x, {3, 3}]; 
Solve[Inverse[P].A.P == B && Det[P] != 0, Flatten[{P, xx, y}], Reals]
```

I want to find the general solution of the above equation (the relationship between parameters), but I get an empty set. What should I do?

Comment: Replace  `Solve` by `DSolve`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you, but the result of using the function `DSolve`  is the input code:`DSolve[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x^3 - 1}] == x, f[x], x]`.

Comment: Your questions are not related. Ask Q2 as a separate question.

Comment: @Montevideo Might  be, but the message "Solve::bdomv: Warning: x is not a valid domain specification. Assuming it is a variable to eliminate." says that there is something wrong  with question #1 `Solve[…]`!

Comment: If you haven't already done so then across the top of the mathematica SE page is a perhaps not obvious box containing "Search on Mathematica" and if you type DSolve integral equation into that box and tap Enter then you may find there have been 29 questions asked on this subject, and some answered. Searching for Solve integral equation results in 410 results. Perhaps something in those might help you. If you have already studied this carefully then I apologize for repeating what you already know.

Comment: @Bill I'm sorry I didn't read the previous posts of the community enough to ask a question. I want to use a more concise and general method to solve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather a math than Mathematica question. Looking in the documentation to the `Solve` command, I don't find any examples of solving functional equations. However, sometimes it works. Indeed, the somewhat corrected command from your question
finds no solution:

```
Solve[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x^3 - 1}] == x, f[x], InverseFunctions -> True]
(*{}*)
```

It seems Mathematica is right in this case. Here are my arguments. The equation under consideration `Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x^3 - 1}] == x` implies

```
feq = D[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x^3 - 1}], x] == D[x, x]
(*3 x^2 f[-1 + x^3] == 1*)
```

and that equation can be solved. Applying the fact that the map $x \rightarrow x^3-1$ is one-to-one on the reals, we have

```
feq /. x -> Surd[z + 1, 3]
(*3 f[z] Surd[1 + z, 3]^2 == 1*)
Solve[3 f[z] Surd[1 + z, 3]^2 == 1, f[z]]
(*{{f[z] -> 1/(3 Surd[1 + z, 3]^2)}}*)
```

Therefore, we conclude that if the solution of the equation under consideration exists, then that solution is of the above form. However, the obtained function doesn't withstand the test

```
Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x^3 - 1}] - x /. f[t] -> 1/(3 Surd[1 + t, 3]^2)
(*ConditionalExpression[-x + 1/3 (-3 + 3 x), Re[x^3] > 0 || x^3 \[NotElement] Reals*)
```

and assumptions about `x` do not help too.